# Applying two different functions to create new column

Tags: pandas, function, apply, multiple-columns

How can I use two different functions with different number of arguments and apply both to create new column in `df`. This works only for 1 function scenario depending on which `apply` method is ran last in line of code. I end up with blank columns if `method=='Totals'` in this case. If I apply `lims_method` above apply `lims_8260` function then I get correct input in new column, but will not work when `method=='TCLP'`. I need to find a way to apply both functions to `df` to create new column without negating the other function.

```
def lims_method (methid):
   if method == 'Totals':
        if methid == '0010/8330B':
            return 'EPA-0010A'
        elif methid == '0010/8270C':
            return 'EPA-0010B'
        elif methid == 'TCO':
            return 'EPA-0010C'
    elif method == 'TCLP':
        if methid == '6010D':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif methid == '6010C':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif methid == '6010B':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif methid == '6020':


def lims_method8260 (meth, matrix):
    if method == 'Totals':   
        if meth == '8260_AZ' and matrix == 'SOLID':
            return 'EPA-8260-S'
        elif meth == '8260_AZ' and matrix == 'WATER':
            return 'EPA-8260-U'

df['LIMS Method'] = df.apply(lambda x: lims_method8260(x['Method'], x['Matrix']), axis=1)

df['LIMS Method'] = df.apply(lambda x: lims_method(x['Method']), axis=1)
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use functions but rather `map`, please provide a minimal reproducible example of an input and the matching expected output

Comment: `.map` and/or `np.select`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments, you should look into using map and not functions; but, if you want a quick fix, you could just combine your functions and make matrix a keyword argument and handle function calls where matrix is not None as you would in your second function:

```
def lims_method(method, matrix=None):
    if method == 'Totals':
        if method == '8260_AZ' and matrix == 'SOLID':
            return 'EPA-8260-S'
        elif method == '8260_AZ' and matrix == 'WATER':
            return 'EPA-8260-U'
        elif method == '0010/8330B':
            return 'EPA-0010A'
        elif method == '0010/8270C':
            return 'EPA-0010B'
        elif method == 'TCO':
            return 'EPA-0010C'
    elif method == 'TCLP':
        if method == '6010D' and matrix == "whatever":
            pass
        elif method == '6010D':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif method == '6010C':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif method == '6010B':
            return 'EPA-1311FULL'
        elif method == '6020':
            pass

df['LIMS Method'] = df.apply(lambda x: lims_method(x['Method'], x['Matrix']), axis=1)
```

It's hard to tell if I'm addressing your concern without some input examples though.